# Channel Entries Search Returning No Results

Tags: channel-entries, search, embeds

I have a routine that searches for an existing customer, based on their member email address. I'm passing the email address as an embed variable:

```
{embed="delivery/charter_customer_form" cust_email="{email}"}
```

The variable returns the address correctly. If I put `{embed:cust_email}` in the template, it displays the correct address.

However, when I plug it into the channel entry tag, I get no results, even I though I know for a fact that there is a match there:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="customers" search:customer_email="{embed:cust_email}" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
```

Also, if I replace the variable with the hard-coded address, it returns the entry I'm looking for.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'd turn on the output profiler and see what the actual query being made looks like (whether the searched value is wrong, empty, or what).

Comment: Interesting. The tag renders the {email} tag as it was passed to the template: `{exp:channel:entries channel="customers" search:customer_email="{email}" dynamic="no" limit="1" parse="outward"}`

Comment: Is there something special about that tag that it won't  render its value inside of another tag? That was the whole reason I felt the need to pass the variable in an embedded template in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to ExpressionEngine parsing order in which user defined global variables are parsed at last. See here http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf

To resolve this problem, you need to have small custom plugin which will return member's email. The plugin code would be like:

```
class Custom_plugin {
    public $return_data;
    function __construct(){
        $this->EE =& get_instance();    
        $this->return_data = $this->EE->session->userdata('email');
    }
}
```

*I hope, you will put other plugin code yourself.*

Now you can have embed variable like:

```
{embed="delivery/charter_customer_form" cust_email="{emp:custom_plugin}"}
```

Comment: That's the only way to search by a person's email address, is through an external plug-in? That just floors me.

Comment: You can try other solution via either Stash (https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev) or Low Variables (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables). These module would work for this purpose. I did preferred using the plugin for this purpose as it seemed me quick and easy :) .....

Answer (score 0):

You might need parse="inward" on your channel entries tag.

Comment: Nope. `parse="inward"` makes no difference on module tags - only plugin tags, and only when that plugin tag is being used as a tag pair.

Comment: You sure about that? Here's an example of Mark Croxton recommending the exact same thing when using a Stash variable as a search parameter: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/7531#25711

Comment: And here's a thread on the EE forums discussing using it on weblog/channel entries too: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55771/

Comment: That did not solve the problem.

Comment: That's cool, just the first thing to check. Try switching `cust_email="{email}"` to `cust_email="{logged_in_email}"` in your embed variable declaration. Any difference there?

Comment: Same thing. It passes the email address, but won't embed it in the  channel entry tag.

Comment: @Tyssen Thanks for that forum thread link, looks like I'm wrong there. (I was taking my info from Low's talk at EECI 2010.)

Comment: @TyMorton Interesting. In theory embed variables should be parsed early so that shouldn't be a problem. I also don't *think* there should be any limitation on passing dynamic variables into the custom field search. In the output profiler is you use {logged_in_email} is this still being shown as the tag itself without processing?